# Explanation of Java 7 configuration on OSX

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, java

I've been developing with Java for a long time, but only recently switched from Windows to OSX. In windows I found everything simple enough to understand. I could install the JDK to a location of choice which also included a JRE. I would then configure PATH, JAVA_HOME etc and I'd be set to go.

OSX seems quite different in its approach. Originally Java 6 came pre installed with the OS. Now I know Apple is no longer supporting that and Oracle is distributing their own version (now Java 7).

Some time ago I installed the Oracle JDK. It seems to have installed at Library/Java/ and added the java control panel to the systems preferences, updated the version of java / javac used in terminal, etc. JDK 6 still seems to be located at System/Library/Java. I'm assuming this is the old Apple version and will be left alone incase I need to use Java 6?

I have a few questions...

Firstly, is my above assessment correct?

Where is config to dictate which tools are used in terminal? There appears to be no JAVA_HOME or entry in PATH when I echo them.

Why is there a link called Home in the Java 7 directory leading back to the old Java 6 tools?

The new Java control panel in system preferences runs updates from time to time. Is this updating the JRE located at Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07/contents/home/jre? Is it also updating the JDK? I ask because after running multiple updates im not sure the version "1.7.0_07" has incremented. The current version on the Oracle site seems to be update 17.

Is there anything I'm missing here? If anyone could explain this rather confusing state of affairs I'd be most grateful!

Answer (score 0):

i'll try to respond by point because you're asking things that are a bit complex.

> Some time ago I installed the Oracle JDK. It seems to have installed
> at Library/Java/ and added the java control panel to the systems
> preferences, updated the version of java / javac used in terminal,
> etc. JDK 6 still seems to be located at System/Library/Java. I'm
> assuming this is the old Apple version and will be left alone incase I
> need to use Java 6?
>
> ...
>
> Firstly, is my above assessment correct?

The old version of java 6 is located under the System/library java, this version in needed by some application to run, if you were wondering which app is it using you can think about the master collection of photoshop (it requires indeed a jvm version 6 to work).

The newer version, managed by oracle, are installed under Library/Java as you pointed out.

> Why is there a link called Home in the Java 7 directory leading back to the old Java 6 tools?

no idea. if comes out some suggestion it will be nice.

> Where is config to dictate which tools are used in terminal? There appears to be no JAVA_HOME or entry in PATH when I echo them.

This guy [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/) has always a lot of solution, anyhow i suggest you to not use directly the bashrc configuration files. You can spot out other solution at the [oracle web site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html#version) and at the general FAQ for mac users [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-install-faq.html).

They are indeed doing a bit of confusion.

Hope that this helps, in case i misunderstood the question or the answer is not complete just ask further.